# JDBC URL connection string to MySQL Replication Group with Single-Primary and Multiple Secondary Instances

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-replication

I have configured *group replication* with single-primary and multiple secondary MySql 8 instances. It works as expected: (1) all secondary instances are in read-only mode in the case the primary instance is on-line, (2)one of the secondary instances switches to read/write mode after primary instance is died.

I have java application which connects to the replication group using JDBC.My URL connection string is likes below

```
jdbc:mysql://host1:3306,host2:3306,host3:3306/database?
failOverReadOnly=false&autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true
```

Let's say failover event has occurred (host1 instance is died) and remaining members of replication group have chosen host3 as a new "primary". Now on the client-side, after host1 failure, JDBC driver has used host2 for some read-only operation which is succeeded.

What will happen if next operation which is by the chance is write operation will be failed? Will JDBC driver re-try with host3 instance and eventually will set it as the "primary" or it will stay with host2 because reading operations are working there?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?